# get the pattern of unknown strings using sql?

Tags: sql, regex, database, sql-server-2008

I have database have thousand of unknow string they may be emails ,phonenum

BUT  they are not for me mean they are not email or cell num for me they are only string for  me but i want their common pattern so here is the string for example purposes

link to example [click here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4cfDSSuJboVTHJmV2k1LXRNZkFmY01iUjNOczM5ejZ1bGFj/view?usp=sharing)

now what i want is this file out put if pattern matcehs 3 time here what i am doing is

```
 DECLARE @strs2 nvarchar(255)
 DECLARE @patternTable table(
id int ,



  order by p.pat
```

but my example return this

```
       485-2889
       485-2889
       ) 485-2889
       ) 485-2889
       .aol.com/aol/search?
      .aol.com/aol/search?
        gmail.com 
     gmail.com
```

but i want to add this for pattern

```
   [a-zA-Z 0-9] [a-zA-Z 0-9] [a-zA-Z 0-9] -  485-2889
```

for gmail 
          [a-zA-Z 0-9] [a-zA-Z 0-9]@  gmail.com

Comment: I would not do something like this in a database. It's not relational work. Pull data into a code layer, handle it there, and then write back if needed.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, this is **much** more work than it might seem.
As far as I can say it's going to be method with heavy processing (and probably not something you want to do with a cursor in SQL (cursors are sort of bad in terms of efficiency).

**You** have to define a way for your code to identify a pattern. You will also have to work in priorities where a set of strings matches multiple patterns. For instance if you implement following pattern criteria (in your example):

```
BK-M18B-48
BK-M18B-52
BK-M82B-44
BK-M82S-38
BK-M82S-44
BK-R50B-58
BK-R50B-62
.....
should generate BK-[A-Z]-[0-9][0-9][A-Z]-[0-9][0-9]
```

Then next set can have multiple patterns as a result:

```
fedexcarepackage@outlook.com (example added for explanations)
fedexcarepackage@office.com
fedexcourierexpress@pisem.net
fedexcouriers@gmail.com ( another example added for explanations)
.....
```

Can generate :

```
fedexc%@%.% (as you said)
fedexc%@%   (depending on processing)
fedexc[A-Z][A-Z]....%@%[A-Z]....[A-Z].[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z] (alphanumeris with '%' to compensate for length difference)
```

in addition to that if you take away `fedexcarepackage@outlook.com` from string list you get 1 additional pattern that you probably don't want to have:

```
fedexc%@%i%.%  (because they have 'i' somewhere between the '@' and '.' (dot)
```

Anyway, that is something you will have to consider with your design.

I'll give you some basic logic you can work with:

1. Create a functions to identify each distinct pattern (1 pattern / function). For instnace, 1 function to check for static pieces of string (and attaching wildcards); Another to detect [A-Z],[0-9] patterns that match your conditions for this pattern to be valid; more if needed for different patterns.
2. Create a function to test a string with your pattern. So say you have 4 string, you find a pattern when comparing first 2 of them. Then you use **this** function to test if pattern applies to 3rd and 4th strings.
3. Create a function to test if 2 patterns are mutually exclusive. For instance 'PersonA@yahoo.%' and 'PersonA@%.net' patterns are not mutually exclusive, if they were both tested to be true. 'Person%@yahoo.com' and 'PersonB@yahoo.com' are mutually exclusive (both patterns cannot be true, so 1 is redundant.
4. Create a function to combine patterns that are NOT mutually exclusive (probably includes the use of function in 2nd and 3rd point). So 'PersonA@yahoo.%' and 'PersonA@%.net' can be combined into 'PersonA@%.%'

Once you have that setup, loop through each text line, and compare Current line to the next against each pattern criteria. Record any patterns you find (in a variable dedicated to that criteria, (don't mix them just yet). 
Next comes the hardest part, safest way is to compare each pattern you find against each of the strings, to rule out the ones that don't apply to all strings. However, you could probably work out a way to combine patterns (in the same category) without cross checking

Finally, after you narrowed own your pattern list to 1 pattern per pattern type. Combine them into 1 or eliminate the ones

Keep in mind that in your pattern detection functions, you'll probably have to test each line multiple times and combine patterns. Some pseudo code to demonstrate:

```
Function CompareForStringMatches (String s1, String s2){ -- it should return a possible pattern found.
   Array/List pattern;
   int patternsFound=0;
   For(i = 0, to length of shorter string){
      For(x = 0, to length of shorter string){
          if(longerString.contains(shorterString.substring(from i, to x)){
             --record the pattern somewhere as:
             pattern[patternsFound] = Replace(longerString, shorterString.Substring(from i, to x), '%') --pattern = longerString with substring replaced with '%' sign 
             patternsFound = patternsFound+1;
          }
      }
   }
  --After loops make another loop to check (partial) patterns against each other to eliminate patterns that are part of a larger pattern
  --for instance Comparing 'random@asd.com' and 'sundom@asd.com' the patterns below should be found:
  ---compare'%andom@asd.com' and '%ndom@asd.com' and eliminate the first pattern, because both are valid, but second pattern includes the first one.
  --You will have a lot of similar matches, but if you do this, you should end up with only a few patterns.
  --after first cycle of checks do another one to combine patterns, where possible(for instance if you compare 'random@asd.com' and 'sundom@asd.net' you will end up with these 2 patterns'%ndom@asd.com' and 'Random@asd.%'.
  --Since these patterns are true (because they were found during a comparison) you can combine them into '%ndom@asd.%'

  --when you combine/eliminate all patterns, you should only have 1 left
  return pattern[only pattern left];
}
```

PS: You can do things, much more efficiently, but if you have no idea where to start out, you probably need to do it the long way and work on improvements from first working prototypes.

---

**Edit/Update**

I suggest you make a wildcard detection method and then apply other patter checks you implement before it.

Wildcard detection for comparison of 2 strings (pseudo code), heavy processing version :

Compare 2 strings, check if every possible segment of **shorter** string is within longer:

```
for(int i = 0; i<shorterString.Length;i++){
    for(int x = 0; i<shorterString.Length;i++){
        if(longerString.contains(shorterString.substring(i,x))){ --from i to x
             possiblePattern.Add(longerString.replace(shorterString.substring(i,x),'*')
           --add to pattern list
        }
    }

    --Next compare partal matches and eliminate ones that are a part of larger pattern
    --So '*a@gmail.com' and '*na@yahoo.com' comparison should eliminate '*na@gmail.com', because if shorter pattern (with more symbols removed) is valid, then similar one with an extra symbol is part of it


    --When that is done, combine remaining matches if there's more than 1 left.
    --Remember, all patterns are valid if your first loop was correct, so '*@gmail.com' and 'personA@*.com' can be combined into '*@*.com

}
```

As for the alphanumeric detection. I would suggest you start by checking length of all strings. If they are the same, run the wildcard pattern detection method (for all of them). When done ONLY look for patern matches in wildcards.

So, You'll get a pattern like `BK-*-*` from wildcard detection run. On second iteration loop take 2 strings and only extract sub-strings that are represented by wildcard characters (use an array or an equivalent to store sub-strings, make sure not to combine both wildcards of a single string into 1 string).
So if you compare with pattern found above (`BK-*-*`) :

```
BK-M18B-48
BK-M18B-52
```

You should get following string sets to process after eliminating static characters:

```
Set 1:M18B and 48
Set 2:M18B and 52
```

Compare each character to opposite string in same position and check if characters match your category (like if String1[0].isaLetter AND String2[0].isaLetter). If they do add that 1 character to a pattern, if not either:

- Add a wildcard character (will lead to pattern like BK-[A-Z]*[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]. If you do this combine adjacent wildcard characters to 1.
- Pattern is false and you should abbort the ch'eck returning no patterns.

Use this basic logic to loop through strings, create (**and store!!!!**) patterns for each set of 2 strings. Loop through patterns, with wildcard detection (possibly a lighter version) to combine/eliminate paterns. So if you get patterns like '*@yahoo.com' and '*@gmail.com' from different sets of strings you should combine them into '*@*.com'

Keep in mind there's **lots** of room for optimization here.

Comment: CAn i add my code by replacing your code so that we start discussing

Comment: @CMM5 solutions: As Zero sais, it seems you are looking for patterns the table's entries have in common. But where to start, where to stop? The pattern `^.*$` matches all entries. So pattern found, work done? Or do you need it more precise? But then how precise? `a@gmail.com` and `a@yahoo.com` both match `^a@[a-o]{5}\.com$`. But this is probably not a pattern you want. So how do you define what patterns you are looking for? What I am saying is: you should not be looking for code yet at all, but for the rules. And these are probably hard to define.

Comment: I GET THE PATTERN YOU ARE RIGHT BUT I NEED
 [a-zA-Z0-9][0-9]a@gmail.com      etc as 'a@gmail.com' is same so before add it

Comment: @CMM5 solutions I've updated the answer to roughly describe the logic of pattern detection. If you find some particular part confuting, let me know - I'll clarify.
Beyond that, I don't think there's much to be said. Wildcard detection will be the core for most of your pattern searches (because it finds partial matches as well as mismatches) so make sure you make it as efficient as possible.